# Is category theory as philosophically intuitive as basic logic?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, category-theory

So far as I understand, category theory can be used as foundations of mathematics as in that the rest of logic can be defined through categorical ideas.

However is category theory as natural a starting point as logic when one wishes to think mathematically?

I’ve often seen that logic is studied outside the context of mathematics in the humanities. However, I never heard of anyone who is in fields related to the humanities speaking about category theory. I'm trying to figure out if this is because of category theory being relatively new mathematics or because it is a less natural/more convoluted starting point to the study of the world.

Comment: Category theory uses basic logic, so it is not the "starting point" anyway. And ZFC set theory, which is a more apples to apples comparison for foundations, is not much taught in humanities either. For applications of category theory to arts, see [Mannone](https://scholarship.claremont.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1519&context=jhm).

Comment: Type theory is the 'internal logic' of certain categories, and type theory can be used in place of FOL. Cf. e.g. Mike Shulman's article "[From Set Theory to Type Theory](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html)" and Lambek and Scott's "[Reflections on a Categorical Foundation of Mathematics](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Reflections-on-the-Categorical-Foundations-of-Lambek-Scott/b4f3448b529a81f781f26fa0df8a0fe546c4ddba)".

Comment: I don't think category theory provides what can legitimately be called a foundation of mathematics because it only describes structures; it does not build up those structures like set theory does. What it does can be better described as providing insight into mathematics than a foundation for mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: all of the following are what I think to be true but am not certain.

> Is category theory as philosophically intuitive as basic logic?

Lawvere first suggested that category theory could be an alternative to set theory as a foundation of mathematics. Set theory can be written in the specification language of first order logic. The same is true for category theory. Lawvere developed a set of axioms which would be written in a formal logic. These axioms define the structure of categories, but they are themselves defined in logic. So it might be a misunderstanding to think that category theory is meant to replace logic.

> So far as I understand, category theory can be used as foundations of mathematics as in that rest of logic can be defined through categorical ideas.

There might be some truth to this. You would probably want to check out topos theory. I don’t know enough about it yet, but in topos theory, a category has an “internal logic”. Thus, a category is a structural way of representing a given logic (intuitionistic, regular, minimal, higher order, etc.)

> However is category theory as natural starting point as logic when one wishes to think mathematically?

Category theory is more abstract. It tends to be harder upfront, but divinely illuminating, and simplifying, over time. From what I have seen, those people who are partial to category theory do not merely just like category theory, they revere it. Once you go categorical, you don’t go back. Any question you are pursuing with set theory can be categorified, and it gives you a completely different view on the same phenomenon. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/horizontal+categorification

> Ive often seen that logic is studied outside the context of mathematics in humanities. However I never heard about anyone who is in fields related to humanities speaking about category theory.

It is happening right now in the world as we speak. People like David Spivak have suggested that category theory has potential as a way to model ontologies: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.1889 Many extremely good category theorists right now are working on categorical data science. Spivak has worked at the company Uber to implement more categorical data structures into their operations. Categorical data is a revolution, because it allows data to be way more inter-operable, and it facilitates expressing things in a compositional way, so that there is a strong computable structure relating the concepts being modeled. String diagrams, a category-theoretic visual diagram, are being used to model systems in general and verify properties about them.

> I'm trying to figure out if this is because of category theory being
> relatively new mathematics or while is a less natural/more convoluted
> starting point to the study of the world.

You could argue that category theory is less naturally intuitive, at first. It was only invented in the 1950’s. One mathematician has said “what mathematics is to the world, category theory is to mathematics”. The key thing is in doing the mental work to understand some of the concepts, what you gain is unbelievable levels of generalization, which results both in much deeper, universal knowledge (as in, instead of knowing something about one particular member of a class of mathematical objects, you can know something about the class of all of them), but also ultimately much simpler understanding too.

Comment: Lawvere started writing about category theory no earlier than the late 60s and 70s.  Eilenberg, McLane, and others were already using it in the 1950s.

Comment: Comments to various points above: CT as "foundational" language compared to Set Theory (and not so much to logic).

Comment: "However is category theory as natural starting point..." For old math practiotioners (like me) set theory is more "natural" compared to CT as well as standard predicate logic presentation is more "natural" wrt old type-theoretic one (that of Church; very cumbersoime). But things changed: modern (Martin-Lof) TT is much more simple (Natural Deduction presentation...) and computation-oriented; thus, more friendly for "youngs".

Comment: "logic is studied outside the context of mathematics in humanities. Correct, but only a small part of ST can be applied in humanities, and similar for CT.